# Argument of type 'HttpRequest<FormData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Request'

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am trying to post a file with `http` client in this way

```
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.API, formData, { reportProgress: true });

        this.http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {...}
```

But typescript shows me the warning

```
Argument of type 'HttpRequest<FormData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Request'.
Type 'HttpRequest<FormData>' is not assignable to type 'Request'.
    Property 'contentType' is missing in type 'HttpRequest<FormData>'.
```

Upon executing I see following `error` in console

```
Error: First argument must be a url string or Request instance.
```

while according to angular's `http.request` definition the first argument can be either a `string` or of type `Request`

```
(method) Http.request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>
```

Also I didn't understand about the property `contentType` missing warning, does that mean I have to explicitly include it in header?

Is there something I doing wrong here?

Edit: I am using

```
"@angular/common": "6.0.0",
"@angular/http": "6.0.0",
```

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? What's the type of `http`. Is it `Http` or `HttpClient`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, it seems that you're using **[`Http`](https://angular.io/api/http/Http)** instead of **[`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)**. Try changing from `Http` to `HttpClient` and check if that works for you.

Don't forget to add the `HttpClientModule` to the `imports` array of your `@NgModule`.

`Http`'s `request` method used to accept the request of type `string | Request`. `HttpClient`'s `request` method on the other hand accepts a request of type **[`HttpRequest`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest)**